While loop acting strangely when using vector::size()
I'm writing a piece of code that's supposed to grow a vector to a certain size. For some reason, the boolean check within the while loop is acting strangely.
Here's the code that I ran; the first loop doesn't run like it's supposed to, but the second one does. To my knowledge, they should both do the exact same thing. What's going on?
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::cout;
using std::vector;

int main()
{
  int index = 0;
  vector<int> vec = {};

  
  //Loop 1
  while (index > (vec.size() - 2))
  {
    cout << "Visiting loop 1\n";
    vec.push_back(vec.size());
  }

  bool test = (index > (vec.size() - 2));
  //I added this here because I noticed that it is initializing
  //as false, even though 0 > -2 is true. In fact,
  //when I type "p index > (vec.size() - 2)" in the debugger,
  //it says true, but when I type "p test", it says false. Why?

  vec = {};

  //Loop 2
  int compValue = vec.size() - 2;
  
  while (index > compValue)
  {
    cout << "Visiting loop 2\n";
    vec.push_back(vec.size());
    compValue = vec.size() - 2;
  }

  return 0;
}


vec.size() is an unsigned type.  vec.size() - 2 is a very very large positive number.

What's going on? -- Look at the issue.  Look at the value of vector.size() - 2.  Also, if you had done the minimal of debugging, this should have been clearly obvious that the problem is that calculation.

You are calculating vector size every time your while loop returns to the condition:
 while (index > (vec.size() - 2))

Therefore when the size gets modified inside the while block you will get a different size when the while loop will be evaluating the condition again.
In the second loop the size is a constant, it doesn't get modified when you get back to the while condition, because you declare it as a constant:
int compValue = vec.size() - 2;

Even if vector size get's modified inside the while block, when the loop returns to its condition the comValue is still the same.
I hope It makes sense.
Also what Tim Roberts said, be careful with unsigned types.

Because vec.size() is an unsigned type, subtracting 2 causes an overflow rather than resulting in a negative number. You can see this if you set
auto t = vec.size() - 2;

So in the first loop initially, index is less than this large positive number. In the case of the second loop, you are converting the unsigned positive number to an int when setting compValue and so compValue is -2 going into the loop. You can fix the first loop by converting the value in parentheses to an int
  while (index > int(vec.size() - 2))
  {
    cout << "Visiting loop 1\n";
    vec.push_back(vec.size());
  }

You probably shouldn't be subtracting values from the unsigned container size in the first place unless you know the container size is greater than or equal to the value you are subtracting. The better fix would be to move the 2 to the other side of the expression.
  while ((index + 2) > vec.size())
  {
    cout << "Visiting loop 1\n";
    vec.push_back(vec.size());
  }



It's not an overflow, it's wrap around. 2) Don't use int for container sizes - it could be too small. 3) In int(size - 2) you still have unsigned wrap around that is followed by implementation-defined (IIRC, it's not UB) conversion into int. Don't do it.

